# Representing a polynomial with linked lists

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, polynomials

Thanks in advance.
For my c++ class, i am tasked with representing a polynomial such as `(MyPoly= 7x^6*y^4 + 4x^4*y^5 - 8x^5*y^3 – 9x + 8)` using linked lists and building Node & Poly classes to help express it.

I don't know how to represent a polynomial with both an X and Y in linked list.

I have an idea of building a linked list to represent the polynomial like `7 6 4 -> 4 4 5 -> -8 5 3 ->-9 1 0 -> 8 0 0 ->NULL`

I am new to this so any example code or pseudo code would be of great help.

[Attempted setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIARy.png)

I came up with this code here(starting point) but i think it will only work for having a single variable and not two (7x^6*... but not 7x^6*y^4). Thanks again :).

Comment: Don't post links to code, and don't post code as images. Copy and paste code as test into rhe body of the question.

Comment: Why a linked list and not an array or a map? What are the specific requirements (what operations do you need to support? Can you use STL containers (e.g. `std::list`,`std::vector`, `std::map`)

Comment: just x,y ? possible z,t...?

Comment: @MikeMB it's an assignment for a class. Presumably it has something to do with linked lists being in the curriculum.

Answer (score 1):

have you thought, or are you allowed to work with the [Horner's representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method) of polynomials? It's not only a much more efficient way to calculate the polynomial values, but can in many cases lead to a more sparse datastructure. For example, the polynom:

[image]

is equivalent to the following expression:

[image]

So there are 3 things to note:

- Actually the one remarkable thing of this schema (although not directly related to your question) is that its calculation is **much faster**, since you save a lot of multiplications.
- The index of the polynom depends directly on the **length of the expression**
- All elements in the expression are **isomorph**, independently of the degree. This is also true for each arity.

So in this lucky case the polynom I chose could be very easily and efficiently stored as the following list/array:

`[7, 5, 1, -4, 1, 8, 1, -7]`

or if you want, as a linked list of **[x_mult|sum]** numbers:
[7|5]->[1|4]->[1|8]->[1|-7]

whereas you know that the elements with even indexes are multiplied by x, and added to the following element, the schema is quite simple.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // the x you want to calculate
  int x = 1;
  // the horner-representation of your polynom
  int A[8] {7, 5, 1, -4, 1, 8, 1, -7};
  int partial;
  int result = 1;
  // run calculations following horner-schema
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (i%2==0){
      partial = A[i]*x; // this mult. is only needed at i=0
      result *= partial;
    } else{
      partial = A[i];
      result += partial;
    }
  }
  cout << "x=" << x << ", p(x)=" << result << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

- **Issues:** You could greatly improve its performance and memory usage if you supress the odd indexes, and take the "1"'s as granted, storing the first 7 elsewhere. Also since the index depends directly on the list's length, polynoms like [image]
  would have a very inefficient representation.
- **Workaround for the memory issues:** A possible workaround would be to inherit your ListElement as ExpandedListElement, so that the numbers in its containers aren't interpreted as factors but as **number of repetitions**. So the ExpandedListElement [1000|a] would mean, that your list has one thousand ListElements that look like this: [1|a]. So the x^1000+3 given example would have two elements: ExpandedListElement[999|0]-->ListElement[1|3]. You would also need a method to perform the loop, which I omit (if you need this workaround let me know, and I'll post it).

I didn't test it extensively, but I assume it's a good approach also for two or more variables. I left also the rest of the OO-implementation details apart, but the core DS and operations are there and should be easy to embed in classes. If you try it, let me know how it works!

Cheers

Andres

Comment: Could you give some info how it can be done with both x and y?

Comment: The paper under this  [link](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiq9oT0pNHLAhVFG5oKHU14D6gQFgguMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.staff.uni-giessen.de%2Ftomas.sauer%2FPubl%2Fhorner.pdf.gz&usg=AFQjCNHj3Bzy5gZMWsghEMx9RImkdTKCeg)  "On the multivariate Horner scheme" (Pena, Sauer) has an algorithm on page 3, but basically it seems a matter of adding more fields to the nodes

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: You're welcome! the solution provided by Humam Helfawi seems a great starting point

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can represent polynominal with a matrix not a linked list or something.

```
   |X^0|x^1|x^2|x^3  
---|---|---|---|---  
y^0|   |   |   |     
---|---|---|---|---  
y^1|   |   |   |  
---|---|---|---|---  
y^2|   |   |   |  
---|---|---|---|---  
y^3|   |   |   |
```

In each cell you should keep the coefficients of x^x' and y^y'. And you can define operations more easily.

You can use [Boost.uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/) for matrix operations.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Besides, how do you represent x^3999718 + y^7514296 + x^255714y^652779 as a matrix? Wouldn't id be a but too wasteful?

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution not so clean:

> MyPoly= 7x^6*y^4 + 4x^4*y^5 - 8x^5*y^3 – 9x + 8

```
#include <list>
class factor;
class polynomial{
public:
    std::list<factor> factors;
};

class factor{
public:
    factor()=default;
    factor(int constant,int x_pow,int y_pow):constant(constant),x_pow(x_pow),y_pow(y_pow){}
    int constant;
    int x_pow;
    int y_pow;

};
int main()
{
    polynomial MyPoly;
    MyPoly.factors.emplace_back(7,6,4);
    MyPoly.factors.emplace_back(4,4,5);
    MyPoly.factors.emplace_back(8,5,3);
    MyPoly.factors.emplace_back(9,1,0);
    MyPoly.factors.emplace_back(8,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be one way of doing it:

Design Considerations:
1. Consider Polynomial as a list of nodes
2. Each node can consist sub-nodes.

So, your class definitions would be:

```
class Polynomial
{
   list<nodes> termList;
}; 

class Node
{
   list<SubNodes> subnodelist;

};

template<class T>
class subNode
{
   int coefficient;
   int power;
   T variable;
};
```

Note: Not tested the code for correctness.

Comment: How does your system represent 5x^2y^3?

Comment: Set it to any variable(x,y,z doesnt matter) and set the power to zero...

Comment: you can handle edge cases the way you want to...

Comment: If 5x^2y^3 is an edge case, what's not an edge case? Why have coefficient where you have it if most of them will be 1 anyway?

Comment: as i said , you can handle it the way u want to..its the simplest design i could come up with..no need of fancy tricks here.agreed with the edge case part

Comment: Perhaps is a bit too simple if you have to fill in lots of redundant data.